# Constant function given an inequality

Tags: functions, contest-math

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies 
 $f(x + y)\leq yf(x) + f(f(x))$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.
Show that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\leq0$.

I tried setting y = 0 in an attempt to prove it but i couldn't and there is nothing else

Comment: Show us your attempts, Nikos.

Comment: Is $y$ anything?

Comment: It is just a variable, i wanted to write that the inequality stands for all x,y in R, not just for x in R

Comment: I tried setting y = 0 in an attempt to prove it but i couldn't and there is nothing else i can think of, i'd be clad if you could help me on this

Comment: @Nikos127 See here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h418798 Good luck!

Comment: This is a question from the 2011 IMO for anyone who's interested. Hint: substitute $y = t-x$.